Owning 2 Google Play Developer Account by a single user-identity
Hello am I allowed to own two Personal Google Play accounts under my one identity?
I want to own two Developer account under my single identity.
I want both accounts to be Personal Accounts and not a Personal Account and a Business Account.

Google's rules say you can have only one Google Play Developer account per person.
